# Android Parse query returns null objectId

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am querying list of users from server. This is not default Parse User class.

I can get all my data except objectId.

While debugging I found it in Object with the objectId needed but unfortinately can't get it anyway.

```
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(PARSE_USER);
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> list, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        for (ParseObject user : list) {
                            User newUser = new User();
                            String idd = user.getObjectId();
                            newUser.setObjectId(user.getObjectId()); // null !!!
                            newUser.setAge(user.getInt(UserPreferences.USER_AGE));
                            newUser.setBio(user.getString(UserPreferences.USER_BIO));
                            newUser.setCity(user.getString(UserPreferences.USER_CITY));
                            newUser.setContact(user.getString(UserPreferences.USER_CONTACT));
                            newUser.setGender(user.getString(UserPreferences.GENDER));
                            newUser.setName(user.getString(UserPreferences.USER_NAME));
                            newUser.setLikes(user.getInt(UserPreferences.USER_LIKES));
                            mUsersList.add(newUser);
                        }
                        mListView.setAdapter(new LoveBoardAdapter(mCtx, mUsersList));
                    }
```

[image]

Comment: Why use oid as foreign key thing when parse haspointers ? Cosider achnge  to newuser. Objectid - making it point to user object.

Comment: Yes, good idea. I have tried it but doesn't help.

Comment: hmmm. it does work. check the browser , verify the col type is 'Array'   see here :: https://parse.com/questions/array-of-pointer  and make sure to 'include' the array col in your query..  Then parse a json ARRAY of the collection of the pointer objects in the query result.